# Mismatch (basketball)

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes, sport

On parle de *mismatch* lorsque deux joueurs aux profils très différents sont adversaires directs (par exemple l'un a un avantage important en taille).

En général, ceux qui sont familiers avec le lexique du basket connaissent le sens de *mismatch*. Quel mot peut le traduire en français, dans ce contexte bien sûr, pour ceux qui ne connaissent pas le lexique spécifique, ou bien ne parlent pas anglais ?

Décalage, écart, situation non favorable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Décalage*** rend bien l'idée.

On peut aussi parler de ***déséquilibre***, ***[différence de gabarit](https://www.swisshabs.ch/petite-difference-de-gabarit-entre-zdeno-chara-et-tomas-tatar)***<sup>1</sup>, du ***contraste*** ou de l'***écart*** entre les deux joueurs.

<sup>1</sup><sub>La différence de gabarit n'implique pas toujours un *mismatch* si elle est compensée par la différence de niveau des joueurs, réciproquement, deux joueurs de même gabarit peuvent être en *mismatch*.</sub>

Comment: Ça ne me semble pas bien cerner le concept. Une différence de gabarit provoque un *mismatch*, mais n'est pas en soi un *mismatch*. Le *mismatch* est la conséquence d'une erreur de l'entraîneur, ou du manque de ressource d'une équipe pour opposer des joueurs similaires à ceux de l'équipe adverse, et est l'expression de l'aspect malencontreux de cette décision/situation, plutôt que de sa cause... Par exemple, deux joueurs de gabarit bien différent pourraient ne pas être si *mismatch* que ça si le plus petit compense son petit format par une vitesse et un talent qui le rendent égal au plus grand.

Comment: @Montéedelait Oui, je comprend la nuance. J'ai modifié ma réponse et ajouté *déséquilibre* qui je crois rend mieux le concept.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connais le basketball que par l'anglais, mon opinion demeure donc à vérifier, et d'aucuns pourront la contester en toute connaissance de cause, mais si ici et maintenant j'avais à en parler en français, je crois que j'opterais pour ***mauvais jumelage***.

<sub>On pourra contester, peut-être à raison, que des adversaires soient *jumelés*. Mon choix vient du fait qu'ils se comporteront sur le terrain comme une paire inséparable, en dépit du fait qu'ils cherchent à se nuire l'un l'autre. Le mot me semble correct, mais mon interprétation de certaines locutions fut considérée incorrecte, il n'y a guère, ici même sur ce site. J'invite donc ceux qui voudraient me laisser savoir que je suis dans les patates en ce cas, à le faire en commentaire ci-dessous. Sans rancune.</sub>